# User-Agent and Blackberry 6.0?

Tags: blackberry

In my application for Blackberry OS 6.0 I am posting multiple image files using HttpConnection, 
here is what I am trying,

```
        byte[] _dataToBePost = strPostData.getBytes();
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String boundary = "----------------------------";   

        String boundaryStartBytes = "------------------------------\r\n";
        byte[] startBytes = boundaryStartBytes.getBytes();

        String boundaryEndBytes = "\r\n------------------------------\r\n";
        byte[] endBytes = boundaryEndBytes.getBytes();  
        _httpConnection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(url,Connector.READ_WRITE,true); 

            // Set the request method and headers
            _httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
            _httpConnection.setRequestProperty("If-Modified-Since","29 Oct 1999 19:43:31 GMT");
            _httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
            _httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");



 if( PhotoToSend != null)
            //if(AttachPhotos._vctAccPhotos.size() > 0)
            {
                String[] strAccidentPhoto = {"AccidentPhoto1", "AccidentPhoto2", "AccidentPhoto3", "AccidentPhoto4", "AccidentPhoto5"};         

                for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
                {
                    String header = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file1\";filename=\""+ "AccidentPhoto"+ i +".jpg"+ "\"" + lineEnd + "Content-Type: application/octet-stream"+lineEnd+lineEnd;
                    byte[] composition = header.getBytes();
                    byte[] photoData = AttachPhotos.get(strAccidentPhoto[i]);
                    if(photoData != null)
                    { 
                        _outputStream.write(startBytes);
                        _outputStream.write(composition);
                        _outputStream.write(photoData);
                        _outputStream.write(endBytes);
                    }
                }
            }
```

in my code I am using User-Agent as Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0. Is this making any problem to post multiple files? Or is there any another way to post the data. 
The code doesn't through any exception but is enable to post Image files only.
What I am missing in my code?

Answer (score 0):

> in my code I am using User-Agent as
>   Profile/MIDP-2.0
>   Configuration/CLDC-1.0. Is this making
>   any problem to post multiple files?

No. <strike>I would also recommend to not touch this header, because it is expected that the OS will set it in a most proper way.</strike>

UPDATE: Thanks to gnuf - I was incorrect saying "the OS will set it in a most proper way". It turns out there will be no such header at all, unless you set it. However I don't think this could be a reason, unless you instructed the server to reject requests if they don't have User-Agent header (which is unlikely).

> Or is there any another way to post
>   the data.

There may be a range of reasons. Basically what you need is to send a POST request of a 'multipart/form-data' type. So you need to correspond to the format of a such request. Some most important possible issues in this case are:

1. Make sure you are using proper "Content-Length" and "Content-Type" headers. "Content-Type" should be `"multipart/form-data; boundary=YOUR_ACTUAL_BOUNDARY"`
2. Make sure you didn't forget to add 2 extra '-' chars to the ending boundary.

Comment: I don't believe the OS will set the User-Agent because it is a property of the HTTP client, not the OS. When you make requests using the BlackBerry's built-in browser, it will set its own user agent string, but when you make a direct HTTP connection, you are free to choose the string.

If you want to emulate the built-in browser's user agent string, refer to http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18169/HTTP_headers_sent_by_BB_Browser_1234911_11.jsp

Comment: @gnuf: you are totally right - just checked what my app sends - there is no User-Agent header. thanks!